# Expect Script scp latest file in directoy

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting, expect, scp

I am trying to scp latest file from remote machine however getting below error;

> can't read "(ssh root@1.1.....   "ls -t /test/*txt | head
>   -1")": no such variable

my expect script ;

```
spawn scp -r   root@$remote_ip:/test/$(ssh root@$remote_ip "ls -t /test/*txt | head -1") /mypath
```

how should I get latest file from remote machine with expect script?

Comment: maybe, you may get the filename before copy, using other command, like:
MYFILE=$(ssh root@remote_ip 'ls -l /tmp/*.txt | head -1 | cut -d\/ -f3')
So, do scp $MYFILE

Answer (score 1):

`$(...)` are shell syntax. To perform the same functionality in Tcl/expect, use the `exec` command.

```
spawn scp -r root@$remote_ip:/test/[exec ssh root@$remote_ip "ls -t /test/*txt | head -1"] /mypath
```

It doesn't have to be a single line, for maintainability, split it

```
set latest [exec ssh root@$remote_ip "ls -t /test/*txt | head -1"]
spawn scp -r root@$remote_ip:/test/$latest /mypath
```

However, I suspect you're using expect to send the passwords, either:

```
spawn ssh root@$remote_ip "ls -t /test/*txt | head -1"
expect "password"
send "$passwd\r"
expect eof
# parse $expect_out(buffer) to extract the file
```

But, your life will be much easier if 
you set up ssh key authentication and avoid expect altogether:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id root@$remote_ip
latest=$(ssh root@$remote_ip "ls -t /test/*txt | head -1")
scp -r root@$remote_ip:/test/$latest /mypath
```

Answer (score -1):

scp -r root@$remote_ip:`ssh root@$remote_ip ls /test/* -1td | head -1` /mypath/.

Comment: No, backticks are *shell* syntax, not expect.

Comment: the tags of the post say **bash ssh scripting**, so please, no down voting